# Show currently displayed results and total results in pagination

Tags: channel-entries, pagination, count

I have the following channel entry tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="designs" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="8" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}

{!--output--}

{paginate}
    <div class="pagination clearfix">
        <ul>
            <li class="pagination-button">
            {if previous_page}<a href="{auto_path}">{/if}
            <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
            {if previous_page}</a>{/if}
            </li>
            <li><p>{current_page} of {total_pages}</p></li>
            <li class="pagination-button">
            {if next_page}<a href="{auto_path}">{/if}
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
            {if next_page}</a>{/if}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{/paginate}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now that pagination displays the current and total pages, but instead I want it to show the current entries range and total entries, like this:

`1 - 8 of 26 results` for page one

`9 - 16 of 26  results` for page two

and so on.

I assembled this string:

`{count} to {absolute_count} of {absolute_results} results`

but I obviously can't just put it in the entry tag as it would parse for each entry. Moreover, {count} references the currently displayed items (ie. {count} will always be 1-8). I would have to do some sort of calculation to find the first count of the page. I assume an addon like [Math](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math) would be suitable.

So to get the correct last count (ie. 8, 16, 24 etc.) the string should only be parsed on the final entry for a given page. What sort of condition could I use to ensure it only parses for the last entry?

Comment: Did Derek's answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big proponent of PHP in templates, but this is a case where it might be your best option. (You could roll this code into a simple plugin as well, which accepted the three required variables at the top as parameters.)

Enable PHP on output, and add this code:

```
{paginate}
    $per_page = 8;
    $current_page = '{current_page}';
    $total_entries = '{absolute_results}';

    $end = $per_page * $current_page;
    $start = ($end - $per_page) + 1;
    $end = ($end > $total_entries) ? $total_entries : $end;

    echo $start.' - '.$end.' of '.$total_entries;
{/paginate}
```